# problema com cookie no curl

Tags: php, post, libcurl

estou desenvolvendo um login com curl e estou fazendo duas requisições, a primeira faz o post para a pagina action do formulário e gera um arquivo txt com o cookie, logo depois eu faço uma requisição usando esse arquivo para acessar a pagina protegida. mas eu não tenho acesso a pagina, o sistema faz um redirect para a pagina de erro.

```
  $tmpfname = dirname(__FILE__).'/cookies.txt';

  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 120);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 120);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $f);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $tmpfname );
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $tmpfname );
  $redirectURL = curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL );
  $status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
  $err = curl_error($ch);
  $ret = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close ($ch);


  $chl = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($chl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($chl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $tmpfname );
  curl_setopt($chl, CURLOPT_URL, $urlll);
  curl_setopt($chl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
  curl_setopt($chl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  curl_setopt($chl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
  curl_setopt($chl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
  curl_setopt($chl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 120);
  curl_setopt($chl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 120);
  curl_setopt($chl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
  curl_setopt($chl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
  $er = curl_error($chl);
  $hy = curl_exec($chl);
  curl_close ($chl);
  var_dump($hy);
  echo $hy;
```

Comment: A minha primeira observação é: Realmente você precisa disso tudo?, você monitorou o site que você está tentando login com `cURL` para ver as requisições a serem feitas? Falo isso porque eu consigo login via `cURL` no twitter e instagram sem ter que utilizar tudo isso de `curl_setopt`.

Comment: Bom dia Guilherme. eu tentei fazer com uma chamada mas como o sistema faz vários redirecionamentos ele não alcança a ultima pagina(pagina protegida).